# MSP430 Assembly Endianness

Tags: assembly, endianness, msp430, microprocessors

*Starting from the address 0x4100 , store the numbers 21,12,32,41 to the memory as bytes.Mind the endian ordering.*

I use the MSP430FR5969. The question is above. My code is:

mov.b #0x41321221,&0x4100

But I cannot be sure about this is true or not. I checked the address 0x4100 from memory browser of CCS. Its content is 21 but other addresses 4101,4102 and 4103 don't include the content 12, 32 and 41. Is this true or not?

Comment: Are all your numbers in hex, even the ones without `0x`?  e.g. `41` means `0x41` in this assignment, not base 10?

Comment: I might have made a mistake. I'm new on assembly language and microprocessors. What should I do to make it correct?

Comment: `mov.b` moves a single byte. So it's only going to move the least significant byte (which is `0x21`) from `0x41321221` into `&0x4100`. That's all it moves. If you want bytes in locations `0x4101`, `0x4102` and `0x4103`, you''ll need to do a separate `mov.b` for those.